# ie8 overflow-y: auto; scroll bar locked by PIE.htc

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, scrollbar

PIE.htc seems to be causing the issue, however I need to keep it for several other effects.

ie8(works fine in FF & webkit)

I have a nested div set with css `overflow-y: auto;` when the scroll bar shows I can use the scroll wheel, click the up/dn arrows and it works fine, however the scroll grab bar is locked, ie when I left click it flashes blue but then back to normal grey and I can not drag it.

Anyone have a work around suggestion

thx
Art

```
.outterDiv{  
  position:absolute;
  min-width: 1000px;
  min-height: 600px; 
  width:99%;  
  height:50%;  
  z-index:100;

  background-color:#212121;  
  color:#fff;  
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;  

  border:1px solid #303030;  
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px; 

  -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #000;  
  -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #000;  
  box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #000;  
  behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

innerDiv with scroll bar

```
.innerDiv{  
  position:absolute; 
  overflow-x:hidden;  
  overflow-y: auto;
  -ms-overflow-y : auto;

  left: 0%;
  width:25%; 
  margin-left:0;

  top: 5.5%;
  height:91%;   
  z-index:900;  
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%;
  padding: .5% 0% 0.1% 0%;

  background-color:#ababab; 

  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;  

  border:1px solid #303030;  
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px; 

  -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;  
  -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;  
  box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;   
}
```